# android googleMaps v2 onMarkerclick comparison

Tags: android, if-statement, google-maps-markers, google-maps-api-2

I have a onMarkerClickListener on my google map which fires when a marker is pressed as it should.

the markers are created in a Tag class that creates the marker within itself on a map that is passed though:

instance of the list at the start of the map activity:

```
//tags
  List<Tag> tags = new ArrayList<Tag>();
```

In the onCreate() of the activity that contains the googleMap I add the markers to a list:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

....other code here

    //add the markers to the map
    tags.add(new Tag(map,1,"City Of Dundee", "Home Of The Jakey", DUNDEE, this.getResources(),R.drawable.ic_launcher));
    tags.add(new Tag(map,2,"Some Place","This is some place",LOCATION_Z,this.getResources(),R.drawable.ic_launcher));

....other code here

}//end on create
```

Constructor for the Tag class:

```
public Tag(GoogleMap map, int atagID,String tagTitle, String tagSnippet, LatLng tagPosition, Resources resource, int id){

    this.tagID = atagID;
    this.position = tagPosition;
    this.title = tagTitle;
    this.snippet = tagSnippet;
    this.icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(id);

    this.theTag = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(tagPosition)
            .title(tagTitle)
            .snippet(tagSnippet)
            .icon(icon));

}
```

This creates the tag and it display on the map properly

In the listener for the onMarkerClickedListener i compare the marker clicked on the map to the marker from the list but the if statement never passes, even when I compare the titles which are identical.

The Listener:

```
onMarkerClickListener = new OnMarkerClickListener(){

    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
        //for loop that goes over array or marker
            //if marker is equal to mark in array
                //do marker functionality
        for(Tag currentTag : tags){
            if(currentTag.theTag == marker){
                switch(currentTag.tagID){
                    case 1:
                    //do something for that button
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "marker 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;
                    case 2:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "marker 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return false;
                    default:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "default", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return false;
                }
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "theTag " + currentTag.tagID + ": " + currentTag.theTag.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "marker: " + marker.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
};
```

I hove no idea why it never reaches the switch statement any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the documentation i was looking for, don't know how i missed it.

As I have read you can't compare a marker using the '==' but you can using

```
if(markerA.equals(markerB)
{
}
```

Like so:

```
if(theTag.equals(marker){
    //it will compare properly this way instead of returning false every time
}
```

Reference to website:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker

Comment: You may also want to have Map<Marker,Tag> instead of List<Tag> and optimize a bit not looping over all Tags but getting your tag in onMarkerClick: `Tag tag = map.get(marker)`. This also uses equals internally.

Comment: I had never heard of a map as such, it would have made my life so much easier haha

Answer (score 1):

You do not need the for loop in your code.  When you do the equality test on the markers(using ==) it will return false, and never reach your switch.  Instead try removing the for loop and just us.

```
            switch(marker.getId()){
                case 1:
                //do something for that button
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "marker 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                case 2:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "marker 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return false;
                default:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "default", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return false;
            }
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "theTag " + currentTag.tagID + ": " + currentTag.theTag.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "marker: " + marker.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Comment: I would love to but i get the error:
`Cannot switch on a value of type String for source level below 1.7. Only convertible int values or enum variables are permitted.`

I'm trying to make it as backwards compatible as possible.

Comment: ah yes, that is a string.  You'll have to replace with if/then statements.  I don't believe android uses Java 7(which supports switch statements on strings).  FYI you will have to use marker.getId().contentsEqual(1))  instead of "=="

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @MaciejGórski comment from the selected answer I would suggest using the ID of the marker (which is oddly a string).

This helps you avoid keeping hard references to Markers which themselves have references to the `GoogleMap` object, and thus the entire `MapView`/`MapFragment`/`SupportMapFragment`

In my class I have:

```
private Map< String, MyObject > markersMap = new HashMap< String, MyObject >();
```

Then when I create the markers I add them to the map:

```
markersMap.put( marker.getId(), myObj );
```

Then in the listener I am able to retrieve myObj like this

```
@Override
public void onInfoWindowClick( Marker m )
{
    Log.v( TAG, "onInfoWindowClick m.getId = " + m.getId() );

    MyObject myObj = markersMap.get( m.getId() );

    Log.v( TAG, "onInfoWindowClick myObj = " + myObj );
}
```

This way I avoid leaking the Views/Activity/Map etc

Answer (score 0):

The == operator will compare the direction of memory of both objects (which are not the same, since are different instances) instead of the object properties.
the equals method, will compare the value of the attributes of your object or if you override the equals you can compare what ever you want, which will be more suitable to you.